# Cmake compilation error

Tags: cmake

I tried to compile a project with cmake, but I got the following error :

```
mostafa@ubuntu:~/oooark$ cmake .
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (message):
  In-source builds are not allowed.
```

For example run:

```
rm CMakeCache.txt
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Are you sure `make` has been installed? Check if both `make` and `gcc` is correctly installed..

Comment: Could you show us CMakeLists.txt at line 19?

Comment: So, why don't you read the error message and do what it says?

Comment: What i understood is __CMake__ uses a file called `CmakeLists.txt` - Input text files that contain the project parameters and describe the flow control of the build process in simple CMake language.` So please check with your CmakeLists.txt..

Answer (score 31):

Do as the help message says: remove the CMakeCache.txt file, create a subdirectory called build, change into that directory, then re-run cmake from there.

```
rm CMakeCache.txt
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

This is because you ran "cmake ." in the top of the source tree. The reason for preventing you running cmake in the source directory is to prevent the source tree getting build artefacts spewed all over it.